# XEP-0430 Inbox query is not working in openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am using openfire 4.6.0 using which I am querying for Inbox( XEP-0430: Inbox) messages but I am getting the following error. Whether the feature XEP-0430 is available in openfire?

IQ Query:

```
<iq id="7025d773-fb53-4afa-89de-3be4d7167277" type="get" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <inbox xmlns="urn:xmpp:inbox:1"/>
</iq>
```

Response:

```
<inbox xmlns="urn:xmpp:inbox:1"/>
<error xmlns="jabber:client" code="503" type="cancel">
    <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
</error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of supported protocol extensions of Openfire is published at https://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/protocol-support.html. The extension that you are looking for, [XEP-0430 'Inbox'](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0430.html), is not listed there.